# How to change the editor type in SharePoint 2010 external content type

Tags: sharepoint-2010, external-contenttype

In our SP2010 site we have an external content type to a peoplesoft database.  One of the types is a string, which displays as a single line of text when editing items in the list.  We need to be able to store more than 254 characters in this data field, but can't figure out where to make that change.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it not by changing the field type, but by adding a little javascript to the editform file to change the maxlen attribute of the textbox.